# String range in VB.NET with multiple occurrences

Tags: vb.net, string, split, substring, indexof

I'm trying to accomplish something fairly simple in VB that I do everyday in JavaScript.

I need to parse text between two strings (HTML tags mainly) that have multiple occurrences.

Sample Data:

```
<tag>test</tag>
<tag>test2</tag>
<tag>test3</tag>
```

If I wanted to grab the data in the 2nd <tag> in JavaScript I would simply do this:

```
var result = string.split('<tag>')[2].split('</tag>')[0];
```

And the only way I seem to get that to work in VB looks like this...

```
Dim from = string.IndexOf("<tag>")
Dim [to] = string.IndexOf("</tag>", from)
Dim result = string.Substring(from + "<tag>".Length, [to] - from - "<tag>".Length)
```

Mind you that is only the first occurrence in VB and already the code looks ridiculous in comparison... I didn't even want to figure out the 2nd occurrence until I find out this is my only solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do about the same thing in VB using the 'Split' method on the String.

```
    Dim sx As String = "<tag>test</tag> <tag>test2</tag> <tag>test3</tag> "
    Dim sp As String = sx.Split(New [String]() {"<tag>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).Split(New [String]() {"</tag>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)
```

Comment: After your response I dug more into it... And turns out you are correct :) I was using the wrong "Split" function trying to use indexOf/Substring.

Solution:

     Regex.Split(string, "<tag>")(1).Split("</tag>")(0)

Comment: check my new issue with splitting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458032/weird-results-when-splitting-strings-in-vb-net