# Weird results when splitting strings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string, split

I was getting weird results when doing multiple splits on a string, so I decided to make a simple test to figure out what was going on

testString "1234567891011121314151617181920"

If I wanted to get whats between 10 to 20 in Javascript I would do this:

```
var results = testString.split("10")[1].split("20")[0]
```

Which would return **111213141516171819**

However when I do this in VB I get **111**

```
Split(testString,"10")(1).Split("20")(0)
```

It seems the 2nd split is only recognizing the first character no matter what I put.

So it's stopping when it finds the next "2" in the string, even "2abc" would have the same outcome even though that string doesn't even exist.

Comment: What happens when you wrap the second split so it's fashioned like the first one?  i.e. `Split( Split(testString,"10")(1), "20")(0)"`

Comment: That worked perfectly Marc! That's the easiest syntax I have seen from other solutions posted... Thanks!

Comment: glad you got it worked out. I added my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the second split so it's fashioned like the first one, i.e.:

```
Split( Split(testString,"10")(1), "20" )(0)"
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Split does not have an overload that takes only a String. The argument is a Char array or String array. Your string is probably being converted to a char array. Explicitly pass a string array like so:

`testString.Split(New String() { "10" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Answer (score 1):

Vb treats the delimiter argument only as a single character.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky scenario that I have seen trip people up before, so I think it is worth a little more explanation than the other answers give. In your original format `Split(testString,"10")(1).Split("20")(0)`, you are unknowingly using two **DIFFERENT** `Split` functions.

The first `Split(testString,"10")` is using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split` function, which takes String type parameters.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split(v=vs.110).aspx

The second `.Split("20")(0)` is using `System.String.Split` method, which does not have an overload that takes a `String` parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split(v=vs.110).aspx

So what was happening is:

1. `Split(testString,"10")` uses `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split`, which
   returns new String() {"123456789", "11121314151617181920"}
2. `(1)` means get 1st position of the returned array, which is "11121314151617181920"
3. `"11121314151617181920".Split("20")(0)` uses `System.String.Split`, and attempts to split on string separator "20"
4. NOTE: The string "20" param gets implicitly converted to a char "2" because the only single parameter overload of String.Split has a signature of `Public Function Split (ParamArray separator As Char()) As String()`.  The ParamArray parameter option allows you to pass a comma delimited list of values into the function, similar to how String.Format works with a dynamic # of replacement values.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx
5. Step 3 code becomes `"11121314151617181920".Split(new Char() {CChar("20")})(0)`, which using literal values is `"11121314151617181920".Split(new Char() {"2"c})(0)`.  The result is {"111", "13141516171819", "0"}.  Get the 0th position, returns "111".

So to avoid confusion, you should convert your code to use the same version of Split on both sides.

**Either of the 2 examples below should work:**

**Example 1**: Using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split`:

```
Split( Split(testString,"10")(1), "20" )(0)
```

**Example 2**: Using `System.String.Split`:

```
testString _ 
    .Split(New String() {"10"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1) _ 
    .Split(New String() {"20"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
```